# Node Express API -- Dynamic Routing with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, routes

I am trying to create a Node Express API and host it on Heroku. I'm using React on the front end to display the data.

I have no problem displaying the data in a list, but I need dynamic routing, so when the user clicks on one of the products, they're redirected to a new page with additional information. With my current code, I get an 'Internal Server Error' and a 404 on the front end

https://shoppingapiacme.herokuapp.com/shopping/
This is a random API that I found, but a good example of what I'm trying to accomplish. If you put an id at the end of this URL, you are redirected to that just that product's information.

Here's a link to mine: http://tentapinodejs.herokuapp.com/tents/

I have very little experience with Node/Express, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here's a codeSandbox of the React with the other Shopping API that I want to emulate. If I try to fetch the data from my API, codesandbox gives a network error. I don't get this network error when using the link in VScode

https://codesandbox.io/embed/cocky-snow-1oi8m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```html
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

app.use(cors())

const importData = require("./data.json"); 

let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello world")
})

app.get('/tents', (req, res)=> {
    res.send(importData);
})

app.get('/tents/:id', function(req , res){
  res.render('tents/' + req.params.id);
});


app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log(`example app is listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

Comment: Please show your templates and JSON data as a [mcve]. Clearly, some link is broken for you, but all I see is a JSON dump and non links, so there appears to be some missing pieces of contextual information here, like HTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I take it you want the JSON data for the one product, based on ID, just like your example?

```
app.get('/tents/:id', function(req , res){
  res.render('tents/' + req.params.id);
});
```

Here you're trying to render a view with the name "tents/", concatenated by the ID, so e.g. some view called "tents/1". If there is no such view with that name it will cause the error you're getting.

Whereas what you want to do (in order to achieve the same result as your example) is something like the following:

```
app.get('/tents/:id', function(req , res){
  const result = importData.filter(data => {return data.id == req.params.id})
  res.send(result);
});
```

This will go through your importData array, find the object(s) with the same ID as the paremeter ID and return it to result.

Here's a Stackblitz per illustration: https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-server-ntz1yg?file=server.js

If you change the url in the preview to https://http-server-ntz1yg--3000.local.webcontainer.io/tents/ you'll get all the data, if you change it to https://http-server-ntz1yg--3000.local.webcontainer.io/tents/0 you'll get the data for the one with ID = 0.